# Pig Latin Rules with Vowels

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I'm trying to write a code that will check each word in a string if there is a vowel in the beginning. If there is a vowel (upper or lowercase) then it will return the word and "-way" appended. If it begins with a consonant, then it moves the first letter to the back and appends "-ay"
Ex: anchor = anchor-way, computer = omputer-cay
.This is what I have but it seems like it's returning all words with these conditions and it's not checking for vowels. What am I doing wrong?

```
def pig_latin(text):
    say = []
    vowel = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    words = text.split()
    for vowel in words:
        vowel = vowel[0:] + "-way"
    say.append(vowel)

        if vowel not in words:
            vowel = vowel[1:] + "-" + vowel[0] + "ay"
        say.append(vowel)

    return " ".join(say)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     result = pig_latin("hi how are you")
     print(result)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Is the spacing in your post the way you have it in your code? If so, this seems like its mainly a spacing issue

Comment: please add the expected result....

Answer (score 1):

When you write `for vowel in words:`, you aren't checking for vowels in words or doing any comparison. The expression `for i in iterable:` is a loop that will one-at-a-time set (in this case) `i` to each item in the iterable. In your case, it is setting the variable `vowels` to the first, then second, then third, ... item in your list called `words`. That is, it is overwriting your `vowel` list you created.

Try something like this.

```
def pig_latin(text):
    say = []
    vowel = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    words = text.split()
    for word in words: # loop over each word in the list of words
        if word[0] in vowel: # compare the first letter of the word against the vowel list
            new_word = word + '-way'
        else:
            new_word = word[1:] + '-' + word[0] + 'ay'
        say.append(new_word)

    return " ".join(say)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     result = pig_latin("hi how are you")
     print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This clarifies my error. I intended for vowel in words to make that comparison in the for loop. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things that you can do.

- use the `lower()` function.
- do not confuse vowels for words.
- use `enumerate` to edit the existing list at the correct index.

This is a working version:

```py
def pig_latin(sentance: str):
    words = sentance.split()
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if word[0].lower() in vowels:
            words[i] = word + '-way'
        else:
            words[i] = word[1:] + '-' + word[0] + 'ay'

    return words

r = pig_latin("hi how are you")
print(r)
```

returns

```
['i-hay', 'ow-hay', 'are-way', 'ou-yay']
```